# When substructures become elementary substructure

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

It is known that given $M\subseteq N$ structure and a substructure such that $M\equiv N$, we do not necessarily have $M\prec N$.

Similarly we can have $M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq M_2$ such that $M_0\equiv M_1\equiv M_2$ that are not elementary substructure to one another.

Is there a chain where this stops to be true? For example, if I have $\kappa$ that is measurable such that $(M_\mu\mid\mu\in(\kappa\cap Card))$ chain of substructures, all with the same theory $T$ (for convenient sake, let's fix some countable language), and (to have somewhat tame behavior) all are bounded subsets of $\kappa$, does there exists cardinals $\alpha<\beta<\kappa$ such that $M_\alpha\prec M_\beta$ (I would imagine that if 1 such pair exists, there will reflect downwards and we will have at least stationary chain of elementary substructures)?

I played a bit with the problem and I think that the answer is yes. Let $\kappa$ be measurable, and $\mathcal U$ be $\kappa$-complete normal non-principal ultrafilter on $\kappa$, and $j$ be the induced elementary embedding on it's ultrapower.

First let's assume that $|M_\lambda|\ge\lambda$ for $\cal U$-large set $X$, as if $|M_\lambda|<\lambda$ for $\cal U$-large set then it is trivial by normality and the fact that $\kappa$ is a strong limit.

Let $Y=\{\mu\mid \text{there exists $\alpha\in X$ such that }\mu=|M_\mu|\}$ and for $i\in Y$ let $Y_i$ be first model of size $i$, $Y$ satisfy "for all $\mu$ we have $\mu\in Y\iff (\mu\in X\land \mu\text{ is larger than every $X_i$ for $i<\mu$})$". Because $\kappa\in j(X)$, the ultrapower computers the $X_i$ for $i<\kappa$ correctly and the ultrapower thinks $X_{\kappa}\ge\kappa$, then $\kappa\in j(Y)$.

In summery we have $Y\subseteq \kappa$ a $\cal U$-large set such that $(Y_i\mid i\in Y)$ is a chain of elementary equivalent substructures such that $|Y_i|=i$.

My next step was to try to reflect downwards some properties on $Y$ to somehow get a fixed point on "approximate"-Skolem hull operation. Basically fix some Mahlo, or limit of Mahlos, $\nu\in Y$ and look at $(Hull_{Y_{\nu}}(Y_\mu)\mid \mu\in Y\cap\nu)$ and hope it will somehow lend on some $Y_\mu\subseteq Y_\nu$, but I couldn't really find a way to do this.

---

Does what I wrote can get me somewhere? If it is indeed true, is there some tighter conditions (as my idea was basically to reflect down to $Y$ all of the LCA I want, so it is obviously an overkill if this method indeed works)?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing like this ever holds, even for very simple theories.

Take for example the language consisting of a single binary relation symbol $E$, and the $\{E\}$-theory $T$ that says that $E$ is an equivalence relation with infinitely many classes, all but one of which have exactly two elements and one of which has exactly one element. Given an ordinal $\alpha$, let $\mathcal{M}_\alpha$ be the $\{E\}$-structure with underlying set $$(\alpha\times 2)\cup\{(\alpha,0)\}$$ where $E$ is interpreted as agreement on the left coordinate. Then for all infinite ordinals $\alpha<\beta$ we have $\mathcal{M}_\alpha\subseteq\mathcal{M}_\beta$ and $\mathcal{M}_\alpha\equiv\mathcal{M}_\beta$ (each is a model of $T$, which is complete), but $\mathcal{M}_\alpha\not\preccurlyeq\mathcal{M}_\beta$ (they disagree about which is the "special" $E$-class).

---

That said, things get much more interesting if we replace "is an elementary substructure of" with "can be elementarily embedded in." **Vopenka's principle** says that every proper class of structures in the same language contains one that elementarily embeds into another. While these days generally believed to be consistent, VP is a very strong large cardinal axiom; its full strength is not immediately obvious but it is easy to see that it fails assuming [the axiom of constructibility](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203576/).

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question, my question is not strictly about the size of the sequence. In the situation my question is focused on I am asking a sequence indexed by **cardinals** such that the domain of the subsets are all subsets of $\kappa$. I see that it is simple to encode your example in the situation I set up, but from the second half of you example it seems like there can be non-trivial situations.

Comment: For example, if I requires $M_i\subseteq i$, I can no longer encode your example in some uniform way that guarantee non will embed to each other (this is an even stronger requirement than elementary embeddable I believe)?

Comment: If I requires $M_i\subseteq i$ and $\alpha$ is definable in $M_i$, then there exists a stationary set of $j$ such that $\alpha$ is definable with the same definition in $M_j$ by looking at a normal ultrafilter and the looking at the function that sends $i$ to the element defined by the definition. (Something similar should be able to happen even if we allow parameters to the definition using the fact $\kappa$ is ineffable), so it looks "almost" like elementary embedding can pop up

Answer (score 1):

As Noah point out, without controlling the domain of the models, there is a little chance to ever have a situation like what you describe.

If we can have some restrictions on the domains we can construct situations with that property, for example:

Let $(A_i\mid i\le\lambda)$ be a continuous chain of substructures whose domain is a set of Ordinals over a fixed language (assume $|L|\le|A_0|\ge\aleph_0$) such that $|A_\lambda|$ is uncountable regular. (Note that it forces $|A_\lambda|=\lambda$)

Taking your idea of taking Hulls: let $(B_i\mid i <\lambda)$ defined as $B_i=Hull_{A_\lambda}(A_i)$, then we have for all $i<\lambda$ some $i<j<\lambda$ such that $A_i\subseteq B_i\subsetneq A_j$.

The reason $B_i\neq A_j$ is from cardinality arguments, and for $B_i\subseteq A_j$, $|B_i|=|A_i|$ so $B_i$ is bounded in $A_\lambda$ (as set of ordinals), by $(A_i)$ being continuous there is some $A_j$ that covers $\sup B_i$.

Let $f(0)$ be the minimal such $j$, for $A_0$, $f(1)$ be the minimal such $j$ for $A_{f(0)}$ and so on.

Let $\kappa$ be the limit of $f(i)$, because $(A_i)$ is continuous we have $\bigcup_{i<\kappa} A_i=\bigcup_{i<\omega}A_{f(i)}=A_\kappa$ but $A_{f(i)}\subseteq B_{f(i)}\subseteq A_{f(i+1)}$ so $A_\kappa=\bigcup_{i\in\omega}B_{f(i)}$, so $A_\kappa\prec A_\lambda$.

---

The requirement of being continuous is the important requirement, it forbid to have new definable elements at *every* stage, only (potentially) the successors. Regularity is just a tool to guarantee that we don't accidentally define our $A_\lambda$.

In the situation of measurable cardinal, even if we require $M_\mu\subseteq \mu$ like you suggested in the comments, we don't have reason to believe our collection will have some continuous subcollection.

In fact, if $\cal U$ is a normal $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$, $Y\in\cal U$ and $Y$ is a set of cardinals such that $Y_i\subseteq i$, then we can reflect being regular and get some ${\cal U}\ni Y'\subseteq Y$ set of regular cardinals, in particular it is very discontinuous.

But we do have a different tool, normality!

Let's add the assumption that $Y\subseteq \bigcup Y_i$. Note that we can assume that for all $i<j<\kappa$ we have $Y_j\cap\sup Y_i=Y_i$ (this is from the fact $\kappa$ is ineffable and the added assumption)

Let $\phi(x;y)$ and $z\in Y_{\min Y}^n$, define $g_{\phi,z}(\beta)$ be the minimal $u$ such that $Y_\beta\models \phi(u;z)$ (otherwise let it be $\min Y_{\min Y}$), this is a regressive function, so there exists $\cal U$-big set $U_{\phi,z}$ such $g_{\phi,z}$ is constant on. Let $U_0=\bigcap_{\phi\in WFF, z\in Y_{\min Y}^{<\omega}}U_{\phi,z}$, this is a $\cal U$-big set.

If $\min Y\in U_0$ we are done.

Otherwise build $U_1$ using $\min U_0$ instead of $\min Y$ and so on for finite stages and let $U_\omega$ be the same but starting from $\min\bigcap U_i$

It is simple to verify that $\min U_\omega=\min\bigcap U_i$ so we are done!

---

As a last note, we can actually state the above as a particular version of Vopenka's principle Noah mentioned:

Let $\kappa$ be measurable and $(A_i\mid i\in\kappa\cap Card)$ be a collection of structures of some fixed small language such that $|A_i|\le i$, and let $h_i:A_i\to i$ be any list of encodings, then there exists $i<j$ such that $h_i''A_i\prec h_j''A_j$.

This is true because there exists only $2$ to the power of the language many theories, so fix some normal $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter $\cal V$ on $\kappa$ and you will find a $\cal V$-big set of indices with the same theory, and from there everything will go smoothly.